# Qt 5.1 - MySQL driver with LAMPP

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, makefile, driver

I have some trouble with my MySQL driver in Qt. When I launch my application I have `QMYSQL driver not loaded`.

So I'm trying to build my driver. I think it's coming from the fact that my MySQL library is in `/opt/lampp/`. So I did the following:

```
~/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/opt/lampp/include" "LIBS+=-L/opt/lampp/lib -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro
```

and then `make`. It's all fine, but when I'm doing a `ldd libqsqlmysql.so` I have this:

```
libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found
```

Thanks for your help. I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

This mean that you haven't install `libmysqlclient.so.18`.
So, open a terminal and type:

```
$ dpkg -S libmysqlclient.so
libmysqlclient18:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
libmysqlclient18:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
```

Then install the needed package:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18
```

Finally re-run your app, as it try to access a shared library you will not need to recompile it.

Good luck !